# passing icon to the parent component

Tags: reactjs

am trying to pass an icon and text to the parent component but is not working, i keep on getting this error but if i pass only the text it will work, pls what could br wrong

this is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import './sidebar.css';
import TwitterIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Twitter';
import SidebarOption from './SidebarOption';
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';

const Sidebar = () => {

return(
    <div>
        <TwitterIcon/>

        <SidebarOption Icon={HomeIcon}  text="Home"/>
        

    </div>
)
}
```

export default Sidebar;

the child component

```
import React from 'react';
import './SidebarOption.css';


const SidebarOption = ({text, Icon}) => {

return(
    <div className='sidebarOption'>
        <Icon />
        <h2>{text}</h2>
    </div>


   );
}

export default SidebarOption;
```

this is the error am getting in the console

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
> built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
> but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
> the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
> imports.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to work with [react-icon](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons), it's a collection of all kind of icons and it's easy to use for example :

**parent :**

```
    const Sidebar = () => {
    
    return(
        <div>
            <TwitterIcon/>
    
            <SidebarOption Icon='FaFacebookSquare'  text="facebook" color='blue'/>
            
    
        </div>
    )
    }
```

**child :**

```
 import * as FontAwesome from "react-icons/lib/fa";
 const SidebarOption = ({text, Icon,color}) => {
    const icon= React.createElement(FontAwesome[Icon]);
    return(
        <div className='sidebarOption'>
        <div style={{ fontSize: 24, color: "orange" }}>{icon}</div>
        <h2>{text}</h2>
        </div>
    
    
       );
    }
    
    export default SidebarOption;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the icon as a component. Like so:

Parent

```
import React from 'react';
import './sidebar.css';
import TwitterIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Twitter';
import SidebarOption from './SidebarOption';
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';

const Sidebar = () => {

return(
    <div>
      <TwitterIcon/>
      <SidebarOption Icon={<HomeIcon />}  text="Home"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Child

```
const SidebarOption = ({text, Icon}) => {
  return(
    <div className='sidebarOption'>
      {Icon}
      <h2>{text}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```